# Does rejecting onsite visit affect's my impression?

Tags: work-life-balance, onsite

So here is the thing.I have been working with my current firm since December 2015. Soon after that, I got married. My managers tried convincing several times for an onsite visit, but I always declined it as I wanted to be with my wife during my initial married life. After a couple of months the managers stopped asking me.

Not complementing myself, but I have been working more than the guys sitting onsite and my tasks completion rate is usually on a higher end in both programming and documentation and the good thing is that my managers are aware of this. Now that the current project is going to end, I am curious if they are ever going to ask me again for an onsite visit. I am comfortable for it now.

Should I just tell them that I am ready if there is any requirement or should I wait for them to ask me again? Would by rejecting earlier have left a bigger impact?

Comment: What do you mean with "onsite"? Does it mean that you work from home?

Comment: Why would an onsite visit affect your married life?

Comment: 1. When you rejected the offer in the past, did you make it clear that it was a temporary issue you had, and that you were open to do the visit in future? 2. What does your work completion rate have to do with managers calling you onsite? 3. If your managers already see you are working well without being onsite, why would they have any requirement to call you now?

Comment: 1. Yes they knew the reason. 2. The reason why they were sending me was to get the work completed as I can interact with clients easily and can complete the development earlier. Although, I managed to do the same staying offshore. 3. Probably, you can see that in point 2.

Comment: No, I don't see the reason for 3 in 2. In fact, it is just the opposite. If you are able to get work done without going onsite, what is the benefit the company gains by calling you onsite?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should I just tell them that I am ready if there is any requirement or should I wait for them to ask me again?

It doesn't take more than a couple seconds to say "By the way, my calendar is more flexible these days and I'd be happy to visit if you're still interested" during a regular videoconference, and I don't see how it'd do any harm. Even if they decline, you'll at least have communicated that you haven't forgotten their request.

Answer (score 2):

It's helpful for folks to have at least a bit of face-to-face time, to help them get to know each other as people rather than just as voices on the other end if a phone line or e-mail connection. It is possible to achieve this without the site visit, but it takes more time and more work.

I tend to be uncomfortable during the first visit even if I *do* already know everyone pretty well, so I too have tended to procrastinate on arranging these visits. In retrospect, that has had costs, just as working from home has had costs -- it has made building networks ore difficult, which has kept me from being able to get involved in some interesting efforts.

Remember that the point of these visits isn't usually immediate productivity -- though there are certainly times when higher bandwidth is helpful! -- but an investment in making the team work together more smoothly, and an investment in your own visibility as a member of the team.

I can't tell you do or do not; I will tell you that it is worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

I would leave it up to them. You're happy enough and working well, they will recognise that fact and that is their main concern. Socialising is great but some people are uncomfortable with it and best left alone. You have possibly been put in that category.

I work with several people I have never physically met and they're great workers so I couldn't care less. Hosting them onsite uses up resources and time, so no worries.